# Internet Explorer 11 Last Session and ASP.Net WebForm App

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, internet-explorer-11

In my asp.net web form application, and I have an issue with internet explorer 11. The user was in "Home.aspx" and when he closes the browser and open again, the browser is still showing the last page "Home.aspx" but this page has no **Session.SessionID** valid, of course, if you click on any other link the user will be redirected to Login.aspx.

My question is, how can I do to redirect to Login.aspx after the last session was restored by the browser? and I do not want to depend of the "Start with tabs from the last session" setting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Edge - Settings - Open Microsoft Edge With... and select Start Page

Comment: I want to know how can omit that setting over my website.

Comment: Since it is a browser setting it would have to been done at the machine/user level